# Regex to parse IRC messages

Tags: c#, regex, irc

I thought it would be neat to parse [IRC messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459) with a regular expression. I got as far as this:

```
(?::(?<Prefix>[^ ]+) +)?(?<Command>[^ :]+)(?<middle>(?: +[^ :]+)*)(?<coda> +:(?<trailing>.*)?)?
```

Then I use this with the following .NET code to get the salient elements of the message:

```
Prefix = matches.Groups["Prefix"].Value;
Command = matches.Groups["Command"].Value;

var parameters = new List<string>();
parameters.AddRange(matches.Groups["middle"].Value
    .Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
parameters.Add(matches.Groups["trailing"].Value);

Parameters = parameters.ToArray();
```

But I don't like that I have to split it separately in code. Is there a way that I can obtain an array of matches from the `middle` group?

Comment: In what format do you receive these messages?

Comment: `RawMessage` is the string.

Comment: A quick search on the internet yield these results: http://news.anarchy46.net/2012/01/irc-message-regex.html http://forrst.com/posts/Regular_expression_to_match_raw_IRC_messages-e0F

Comment: @Eve Neither of those answer my question: Getting an array of parameters. As you can see, my regex already does what those regexes do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Captures` property of a repeated group, although I wouldn't advice it.

First you would need to change your pattern to:

```
@"(?::(?<Prefix>[^ ]+) +)?(?<Command>[^ :]+)(?<middle>(?: +[^ :]+))*(?<coda> +:(?<trailing>.*)?)?"
```

Secondly, you would do:

```
parameters.AddRange(match.Groups["middle"].Captures.
                    OfType<Capture>().
                    Select(c => c.Value));
```

Comment: @Superbest Not every language supports repeated capturing groups (for example Java). If you ever had to port your code you'd most likely run into nasty bugs.

Comment: @Eve When you always use this argument, then you would end up writing Brainf*ck compatible code.